# Como obter CEPs próximos através via Geolocalização ou GPS no IPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, gps

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo de *delivery*, mas estou com dificuldades para obter o CEP automático através de minha localização.

Utilizando a biblioteca *CoreLocation* do IOS, até obtenho o CEP, mas apenas os 5 primeiros dígitos e em alguns pontos é retornado NULL

Existe alguma forma mais confiável para obter mais essa informações de acordo com a localização, no caso o CEP das ruas que me cercam?

Answer (score 1):

Cara, eu faria o seguinte, eu pegaria o endereço do CoreLocation que conseguimos pegar normalmente e usaria uma API de consulta grátis, com uma consulta a partir do endereço, uma simples é esta: http://avisobrasil.com.br/correio-control/api-de-consulta-de-cep/